# Samsung SmartTV ovelray (news ticker) application

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv, television

Is there any way the application can run as an overlay (ticker) over the DVB program (i.e. live broadcast)?

Currently the only working solution to display application as an overlay over part of the screen, we are aware of, is to start the application from TV SmartHub menu and display the overlay over the IP (usually HLS) stream.

See for example here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CNBC_Closing_Bell.jpg) the CNBS ticker. We would like to develop the application like this... to display additional info over the DVB (or other) broadcast.

Regards,

STeN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run application in a SmartHub and use TV source as a background of application this should help you:

For the method:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Window/SetSource

And for enumeration of sources:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Window/SetSource

It is only my guess because I have never needed to play TV in background - always used the PL_WINDOW_SOURCE_MEDIA as I'm working on Internet video streaming.

Remember that you need to have transparent background in your application CSS, because video in Samsung plays always under the  background.

Hope It help!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer!! Can I ask you if you ever heard about the possibility to start the application after TV is switched on? Imagine the scenario, in which you run ticker application showing sports result. It will be pretty annoying to go every time you turn on TV to SmartHub ans start it. Is there any possibility to keep it running next time you start the TV?

Comment: No, there is no normal way for that... There is SamyGO project - custom firmware for Samsungs http://www.samygo.tv/ where you can do that - but you know - you can void warranty ;)