# Samsung Smart TV VOD App - How to switch from source to player and back to source

Tags: javascript, html, css, samsung-smart-tv

Working on a video on demand (VOD) app for Samsung Smart TV using the 2.5 SDK, I have pretty much all the functionally working.

The app should runs overlayed on live program but the screen is black (no source) then I select video, player loads and the video turns on and also when I exit the app the source gets lost... in my config.xml I have the following

> > fullwidget itemtype="boolean" = y 
> >     movie itemtype="string" = y 
> >     srcctl itemtype="boolean" = y

in addition to that i'm calling plugin.Stop() on onUnload

Has anyone else experienced this issue and, if so, did you manage to fix it?

PS: when srcctl = n the source comes up on the initial load but the vod loads with no audio and only source audio when exit the app source gets lost all together.

check the code shown below:

```
Main.onUnload = function(){
Player.deinit();
}
Player.deinit = function(){       
      if (this.plugin)
      {
            this.plugin.Stop();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app should runs overlayed on live program but the screen is black

So if you hear the source sound and screen is black you probably need to check if your body background is set to transparent as video and source in Samsung is played under the document body.

And when you switch between source stream and VOD you probably need to change the PL_WINDOW_SOURCE parameter. Check my older answer about it:

[Samsung SmartTV ovelray (news ticker) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102923/samsung-smarttv-ovelray-news-ticker-application/10137818#10137818)

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Window/SetSource

Comment: this is what i have on my Player.init()                             var mwPlugin =  document.getElementById("pluginTVMW");
this.originalSource = mwPlugin.GetSource();                                             and on Player.deinit()                                                         var mwPlugin =  document.getElementById("pluginTVMW");
mwPlugin.SetSource(this.originalSource);                                  would this work?

Comment: Thanks man worked like a charm...but so far i'm able to store only the active source...like so mwPlugin.SetSource(this.originalSource); returns 0. mwPlugin.SetSource(34) directly into HDMI4; but it should dynamicly return the active source no? let me know if you have an idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you precise your question, because i don't understand it right now. You can use `GetSource()` method on the beginning so you'll find what Source user originally used.