# Getting raw stream data from Samsung smart TV

Tags: air, samsung-smart-tv

Hi I am trying to develop a ticker for Samsung smart TV, that needs to get the RAW audio\video displayed from the live cable TV service in order to react to it. I got all the Samsung eclipse development tool and Adobe Air for TV environment ready. But how do I get the audio\video stream pip from the TV to the Air application? Is their a known native C Air plugin to do that, or some other Samsung API?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung doesn't give you possibility to play Samsung TV source inside Flash.
I've checked the documentation and it looks like you need to use Samsung native JavaScript API.

Here you have Samsung sample which is using `ExternalInterface.call();` to communicate with JavaScript API.

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/Flash/Access_Flash_Content/Tutorial_Accessing_Flash_Using_Player_and_Audio_APIs_Externally

In the sample are player controls like play/stop/pause made in flash and the video player is the Samsung's native plugin.

So in your situation first you'll need to create JavaScript application which will play TV source in background. I was explaining it here:

[Samsung SmartTV ovelray (news ticker) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102923/samsung-smarttv-ovelray-news-ticker-application/10137818#10137818)

And then implement your Flash part. It is possible to make transparent background so Flash content can be displayed over TV source.

Don't hesitate to ask if you need more explanation.

Comment: Hi Dobiatowski thanks for the elaborate reply. Its seems that Samsung does not have an API for getting any raw stream from the TV, but I see that Skype application got the raw data from the microphone and the camera. So I am missing something here... 

If I give up on getting raw live TV I want to at least have raw microphone \ camera streams. Do you know how Skype did this? I looked at the forums and ppl said microphone stream is not supported for Air. I am currently trying this out myself. Have any idea?

Comment: In my opinion Skype as a Samsung's partner have access to undocumented API and you will not have access to this. But this is only my opinion - and I'm also interested to get access to this features.

Comment: :P will let you know if i'll get them!